# Angular circle directive define

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to build generating widget. I believe the problem of mine code is where array is empty but ng-repeat is still returning code from directive. [This is small example of mine code](http://plnkr.co/edit/KpXIQiNYVc51c0nLFub3?p=preview), when you change item.html file content to `<view>` the page is freezed.

index.html

```
<div ng-repeat='item in obj.items'><item></div>
```

index.js

```
$scope.obj = {
    level: 1,
    items: [],
    views: []
};
directives.view = function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: "view.html"
    };
}
directives.item = function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: "item.html"
    };
}
```

item.html

```
<view>
```

view.html

```
<div ng-repeat='item in item.items'><item></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your directives really are nothing more than templates you may want to consider simply using `ng-include` instead:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in obj.items' ng-include=" 'item.html' "></div>
```

Comment: Mine directives is only templates of html. Give me few minutes to try this

Comment: Yep, it works. I guess ng-include run only when there are actual lines of code, so it not try to define any directive. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your `plunker` (see description below).

here is the fixed `plunker`:

### http://plnkr.co/edit/fF8Z5JeHOr2XeNTCPkho?p=preview

**index.html**

```
  <body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ctr">
      <a ng-click="addItem()" class="btn btn-primary">ADD ITEM</a>
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <item></item>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**item.html**

```
<hr/ >
<h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
<h5>{{item.date | date:'medium'}}</h5>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller('ctr', function($scope, $sce) {

  $scope.items = [];

  var counter = 0;

  $scope.addItem = function() {

    var item = {
      name: ++counter,
      date: new Date()
    };

    $scope.items.push(item);
  }
});


app.directive('item', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'item.html'
    };
  });
```

---

**Errors fixed:**

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngSanitize
```

You need to include this module or change `angular.module('mainApp',['ngSanitize'])` to `angular.module('mainApp',[])`

**Id addition**, your `view.html` included himself e.g.

`<div ng-repeat='item in item.items'><item></div>`

this will also cause an error eventually

Comment: You have lost a point of problem, index should genete item directive, which should generate view directive, which generate item directive etc. Each generate is from a button.